# Installing modules using Strawberry Perl

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, perl-module, strawberry-perl

Until now I used [ActiveState](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState)'s [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl), and used the ppm for installing modules.

Last week I moved to [Strawberry Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl), but I don't know how I should install modules using Strawberry Perl. What is some information on how module installation is done using Strawberry Perl or is there some link on how to install new modules?

Answer (score 69):

You can still use `ppm`, but it is not recommended. Run *CPAN client* from the *Strawberry Perl* or *Strawberry Perl (64-bit)*, sub folder *Tools*, entry in the Start menu.

Type `install Module::Name` there.

Comment: On Windows 7, `Start Menu > Strawberry Perl > Tools > CPAN Client `

Comment: On Windows 8.1, `Start>Cpan Client`

Comment: On Windows 10, Start Menu > All Apps > Strawberry Perl > CPAN Client

Comment: I've done the install Module::Name (Date::Calc in my case), but program still fails saying `code` Can't locate Date/Calc.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Date::Calc module) (@INC contains: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib) at .\Create_DELETE_XML_20220602.pl line 3. `code`

Answer (score 42):

As [Alexandr says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643939/installing-modules-using-strawberry-perl/6644328#6644328), you can use the CPAN client via the start menu. You can also install modules just as you would on Unix from the DOS window:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Quantum::Entanglement
```

You can also download the .tar.gz from CPAN, unzip it and install as you would in Unix:

```
cd Module-Name-1.23
perl Makefile.PL
dmake
dmake test
dmake install
```

You may need to make sure your [%PATH%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable has the right entry to get to Strawberry Perl, and does not contain other copies of dmake or gcc, which will sometimes lead to headaches.

Comment: "cpan" is shorter than "perl -MCPAN -e shell"

Comment: well, yes, but I like to be able to check perl -v first to know which Perl I'm running.

Comment: As Alex said, it works fine with: cd Module-Name-1.23 perl Makefile.PL dmake dmake test dmake install `dmake` is a `make` program that happens to run pretty well on Windows, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777261/what-is-dmake-actually-doing-when-installing-a-new-module).

Comment: you can do it in one line: 

  `cpan Quantum::Entanglement`

Comment: also you can use `cpanm` instead of `cpan`. `cpanm` might be better if you are new to this, as it has less messages and configuration.

Comment: The *`You may need to make sure [...]`* considerations only apply to the second version, right?

Comment: No, it applies to both.

Comment: Strawberry Perl has deprecated `dmake`, and you should use `gmake` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Change the directory:

```
cd C:\Strawberry\perl\bin
```

Then

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>cpan Lingua::EN::Sentence
```

and the module will install automatically.

Answer (score 3):

CPAN is the easiest installation method.

As [Alex has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643939/installing-modules-using-strawberry-perl/6644519#6644519), you may have to download a .tar.gz and unzip it. Since he wrote his answer, Strawberry Perl has deprecated [dmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Derivatives), and you should use [gmake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Derivatives) instead.