# PERL xampp PPM Error

Tags: perl, xampp

C:\Users\Jason>ppm version
Can't use an undefined value as a SCALAR reference at X:/ampp/perl/vendor/lib/PP
M.pm line 1684,  line 41.

there were more errors initially which I solved. 
Error No 1) libexpat-1_.dll was missing. downloaded libexpat.dll and renamed it to expat-1_.dll and stored it in [perl]/bin

Error No 2) Couldn't read ppm_dat. I used ppm > gencode and created a basic repository and added it to the bin directory again. that was solved..

Now the above error is the 3rd error which I'm too new to perl to solve.. Any help will be appreciated.

The final goal is to install bugzilla on xampp.

Comment: If you're willing to get a better perl for windows, there is `strawberry perl` http://strawberryperl.com/ or `active perl` from http://www.activestate.com/activeperl

Comment: Very little to go on here; but I presume you're trying to install modules via ppm on the strawberry Perl that comes bundled with xampp. Maybe this thread will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694119/why-is-it-discouraged-to-use-ppm-perl-modules-with-strawberry-perl-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

ppm is looking for the environment variable "PPM_DAT," which seems to be missing; add it, with the value "<xampp path>\perl\site\lib\ppm.xml."

I was getting this error too, & that's what fixed it for me.