# Read password using Perl on Windows without using CPAN packages

Tags: perl, passwords

We have a Perl script that uses the terminal to read a password. This script does not work on Windows as the terminal is not available.

We did some research and found that ReadKey/Readline is an alternative for this. However, this package is not part of our default Perl install.

Is there a way to read a password in Perl without using the terminal or ReadKey/Readline?

Comment: Which Perl distribution are you using on Windows? Is is ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl?

Comment: "without CPAN packages?" ... Short answer, no.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way of getting the password without echoing in the terminal, try this:

```
use Term::ReadKey;
print "Enter password:";
ReadMode('noecho'); 
my $password = <STDIN>;
chomp($password);
```

Later, if you have to back to normal terminal input echo, write this:

```
ReadMode(0);
```

This solution requires the installation of [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadKey), and it works it Windows also.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions on installing CPAN modules with ActivePerl may be found here:

[How to install CPAN modules into ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2010/10/how-install-cpan-modules-activeperl)

Instructions on installing CPAN modules with Strawberry Perl may be found here:

[Strawberry Perl CPAN instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643939/installing-modules-using-strawberry-perl)